# 2D density plot with plotnine (stat_density_2d)

Tags: python, plotnine

I am trying to create a 2D density plot using python's `plotnine` along the lines of the last example here:  [https://r-graph-gallery.com/2d-density-plot-with-ggplot2.html#:~:text=A%202d%20density%20plot%20is,of%20points%20in%20this%20fragment](https://r-graph-gallery.com/2d-density-plot-with-ggplot2.html#:%7E:text=A%202d%20density%20plot%20is,of%20points%20in%20this%20fragment).

It should look roughly like the following (constructed using `geom_bin2d`), but smoother.

[image]

I have tired:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotnine import *

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.random.normal(1,1,10000),
    'y': np.random.normal(3,2,10000),
})

p = (ggplot(df, aes('x','y'))
  + theme_light()
  + stat_density_2d(aes(fill='..level..'), geom='raster', contour=False)
  + labs(x=None,y=None)
)
p
```

But end up with just a yellow blob:

[image]

Is it possible to do this in `plotnine` using the data as is, or do I need to do additional data transformations etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should map the `fill` to the `density`. The `level` is demarcated by lines while the density by regions.

```py
(
...
+ stat_density_2d(aes(fill=after_stat('density')), geom='raster', contour=False)
)
```

Then set the interpolation method to smoothen it.

Comment: Thanks @has2k1, appreciate it and love your work.  Could you include in the answer how you would set the interpolation method?  I tried 'interpolate=True' as per geom_raster() and got an error that interpolate was not understood.  This aspect is not covered in the documentation: https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.stats.stat_density_2d.html

Comment: e.g. `interpolation='gaussian'`, see the documentation for [geom_raster](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.geoms.geom_raster.html)